# Rails Connect with Postgresql database in application ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am using **ubuntu 12.04** and **rails 3.2**. I am creating a rails application in which I'm using **PostgreSQL** databse. I installed postgresql using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

for reference i checked out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL. Later I created the user postgres and set the password postgres using the following command

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
\password postgres
```

Next I created the database using:

```
 sudo -u postgres createdb mydb
```

I tried to connect with Postgresql with the username **postgres** and password **postgres** and got successfully connected with the following command:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.1.4)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
postgres=#
```

In my rails app my database.yml has the following code:

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: mydb_development
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: postgres

test:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: mydb_test
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: postgres

production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: mydb_production
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: postgres
```

Now when I run the command `rake db:migrate` i get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I tried adding host: localhost to database.yml for each environment and i get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
couldn't parse YAML at line 28 column 0
```

The line 28 is

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: hackathonio_development
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: testing
 host: localhost {This is line 28}
```

Please help me figure out a solution for this..

Comment: Does adding `host: localhost` to the bottom of each environment fix the problem?

Comment: There is an answer to that in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987171/rails-3-2-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-pgerror

Comment: @dezso Can you tell me a command to check if those DB's exist. I checked out lot many links but dint get an appropriate solution.

Comment: Try this: `psql -U postgres` and then `\c mydb_production` for example.

Comment: I think there is indentation of 2 in YAML? no? odd that you should get yaml parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have 2 problems. First, the host not being set as Shreyas pointed out. But I believe the second problem is that when you set the hostname Rails is trying to connect to PostgreSQL via a tcp socket and not a local ruby socket. My guess is you need to modify your `pg_hba.conf` file to allow postgres to login via localhost. Below are a few SO questions with answers that may help.

[Rails can't login to postgresql - PG::Error - password - Correct info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630177/rails-cant-login-to-postgresql-pgerror-password-correct-info)

[What's the difference between "local" and "localhost" connection types in pg_hba.conf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913897/postgres-whats-the-difference-between-local-and-localhost-connection-type)

[Can't use postgres user in new database for rails 3 on ubuntu 10.04 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246950/cant-use-postgres-user-in-new-database-for-rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-server)

Answer (score 0):

Please add host to your yml as localhost

Comment: I did as you said but i again got an error. I edited my question and mentioned the error.

Comment: Add 127.0.0.1 in your host and please remove the {} in your yaml file

Comment: {} is not present in yaml file. I jst wrote it to specify the line number.

Comment: Then please check spaces in your YAML file. YAML is not able to read your yaml file properly I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation:

**Step 1**

Create a new, different user by running

```
$ createuser <username>
```

on the command line. You'll be prompted for password, etc. (Examples/docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-createuser.html)

**Step 2**

Update `database.yml` with the new users's username/password. Forget the first user you created, at least for now.

**Step 2**

```
$ rake db:create
```

**Step 3**

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

I think those steps are more likely to work that what you're trying.